# How to achieve such grunge texture?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture, technique

I just came across the works of Forthcoming Studio ( https://forthcoming.studio/) and I was really wondering how it's possible to achieve such texture effect and what is the source for it ? Are those brushes, pictures with displacement map...? I have no idea but I'd be thrilled to learn :-)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this was all made in Photoshop to be honest. Looks mostly like vector work.

1. The dot pattern looks like a halftone pattern. This part could be done in Photoshop by converting a photograph to greyscale, then bitmap, and choosing a halftone pattern as the conversion method.

[image]

2. Then the image imported into Illustrator, and auto traced, ignoring white.
3. The trace Expanded, fill changed to grey with a black stroke set.
4. Parts deleted using the Eraser tool to create blank areas, and other pieces of the halftone selected, copied and pasted and rescaled.
5. Text underneath
6. Black background at the bottom

A very rough example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No one can say *specifically*.

However, chances are it's *vector based* (Illustrator, Inkscape). The elements are well defined and there's no reason to automatically think this was created in Photoshop. It could be, but it would be faster and easier in a vector-based editor. There are simply several layers of different elements...

Bottom up...

- A background for the black
- A type layer containing the text
- A layer containing the tiny numbers
- A layer containing the white circle elements
- A layer containing the grey circles

Now, how one goes about generating the element on each layer can be a bit involved and covering all of them is probably too broad a question. You may be better to focus on one aspect at a time.